# mkdir() returns No such file or directory in <b>...</b> on line <b>..</b><br />

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm PHP developer but i cant understand this error

```
$uid = $this->db->Tables("telegrambots")->search([
  "telegrambotid" => $this->botKey
])['uniqueId'];
if (!file_exists("TelegramBotCommands/{$uid}"))
  mkdir("TelegramBotCommands/{$uid}");
```

Comment: The Videos class is required in top

Comment: Is there a more useful error message in the PHP logs?  "500 error" isn't really an error message, it's just the server telling the browser that something failed.

Comment: what's your actual problem? Why do you need to use eval? most cases - you don't need it

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: eval is evil, if you can (and you almost always can), try to avoid it

Comment: @treyBake i need dynamicly call classes

Comment: @MDReal you don't need eval to do that..

Comment: another variant i cant find. if else or switch case is so long. i want automate it without enter all manually

Answer (score 1):

Eval is evil, you probably don't need it so don't use it. You want to make a call to a class with a dynamic name? Use this:

```
$dynamic_class_name = 'Video'; 
$video = new $dynamic_class_name();
```

That being said, your snippet with eval seems to work perfectly fine:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3bb43b1ccfd27365247120e9c5751aac9e2b4ce

You would have to check your logs as to what the error is.

EDIT:

As you said you are using namespaces, try to use the full classname including the namespace in the eval function (like `new \namespace\Videos(...`. Even better though: don't use eval!

Comment: Thanks, I use namespaces. I dont why but in logs return The class Videos not found

Comment: Make sure to use the full class name in eval, including the namespace (`\my\namespaces\Videos`). See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks That worked. Use full namespace